# Unnecessary fail page when login with yahoo mail account

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

i just had an error message on stackoverflow.com when i tried to log in by my yahoo mail account. It was suggesting me to give feed back here, so here it is:

Eventhough i get error during login page, i'm able to see my account name on upper right corner and stackoverflow logo on the upper left side i can see main page where all questions listed. I think the problem is site couldn't redirect me to main page after login.

I attach screenshot here, so maybe i may help developers of the site :)
*edit: my os is windows 7 ultimate and my browser is google chrome 
[image]

Comment: What browser, OS and version?

Comment: Hi, i forgot to mention. I use windows 7 ultimate and my browser is google chrome

Comment: Can you try clearing all your cookies and logging back in? Let me know if the error persists?

Comment: Hi, it didn't occur this time. But i already cleared my cookies etc. just 2 hours ago and i only used gmail on browser and libre office since that

Comment: How did you get logged out in the first place? Did you see "Welcome banner" on top of the page when logging in?

Comment: Honestly, at that moment i wasn't paying attention that since i'm at the office :/

Comment: @Oded: I've been getting this same problem with Google login for the past week. It sometimes works, it sometimes doesn't :s When it doesn't, I get the error kitty, but the topbar shows that I'm logged out.

Comment: @Oded don't you have access to the error logs? Maybe you'll find something in there?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nothing to see there, not for that IP.